# Iphone: Does a custom made UIView needs a dealloc

Tags: iphone, release, nib, dealloc

I have a custom made uiview class, and i have a dealloc with other releasing call within it.

In this custom uiview, I have 3 outlet of controls : buttons, textview etc. When the custom uiview deallocated, I received this error: Error for object 0x88782c0: pointer being freed was not allocated.

Inside the code, I have not release any of these outlet at all. When I removed those 3 outlet of release call, the error was gone. Do I need to deallocate those outlets.

```
[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ParanoidView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] autorelease];

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

    [self addSubview:self.view];
```

The above code is add within the initWithFrame call to load the nib file.

Comment: Is my old project that uses non-ARC . so if i change it, I have to change a lot of things

Comment: Honestly, converting to ARC is much faster than you think, and in the end, you will have a much more stable application, and the code will be much cleaner.

Comment: Ok i really change it later ... What are the changes mainly

Comment: In the menu at the top, select **Edit**, then **Refactor**, then **Convert to Objective-C ARC**. It will give you a list of things you need to change. Most of it should be automated though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code.

```
[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ParanoidView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] autorelease];
```

You cannot release or autorelease something you didn't retain. Period.